# Shortcode content is empty

Tags: shortcode

I've got this shortcode in my `functions.php`:

```
function amaranthe_buy_tickets( $atts, $content = null ) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'link'  => '#',
        'target'    => '',
        'variation' => '',
        'size'  => '',
        'align' => '',
    ), $atts));

    $style = ($variation) ? ' '.$variation. '_gradient' : '';
    $align = ($align) ? ' align'.$align : '';
    $size = ($size == 'large') ? ' large_button' : '';
    $target = ($target == 'blank') ? ' target="_blank"' : '';

    $out = '<a' .$target. ' class="tickets_btn' .$style.$size.$align. '" href="' .$link. '">' .$content. '</a>';

    return $out;
}
add_shortcode('buy-tickets', 'amaranthe_buy_tickets');
```

In my template file where I want the shortcode to display, I have this:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[buy-tickets]"); ?>
```

and in the post, I have this:

```
[buy-tickets]Tickets[/buy-tickets]
```

In the output, all I get is this:

```
<a href="#" class="tickets_btn"></a>
```

For some reason, the content is missing.

Comment: Impossible. Your output cannot be a result of your shortcode (`href` comes after `class`). Please add the real output, do not use the DOM inspector, use source view instead.

Comment: this is what I get when I view source   <a class="tickets_btn" href="#"></a>. I don't know what you mean "Your output cannot be a result of your shortcode href comes after class" Why does that matter?

Comment: I does matter, because we _know_ we are either not looking at the real output or you have overwritten the shortcode you want to fix with another shortcode that produces _almost_ the same markup. This is important. We cannot help if the facts are obviously wrong. :)

Comment: There is no other shortcode. That is the code word for word in my functions.php file. it's doing the shortcode but none of the content. none of the arguments are working.

Comment: got it sorted out. There was an error in my query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the hyphen:

> Take caution when using hyphens in the name of your shortcodes. In the
>   following instance WordPress may see the second opening shortcode as
>   equivalent to the first (basically WordPress sees the first part
>   before the hyphen):

Rename your shortcode so the tag doesn't have a hyphen.

Comment: I think I remember something about hyphens killing the shortcode. I thought this would work but I tried it and still it's not working. It doesn't seem to be accepting the arguments either. I put in link like so link="address" and it shows the # sign in the url.